# Sources of magnetic fields and violation of conservation of energy

Tags: electromagnetism, energy-conservation

We know that current is a source of magnetic fields, for example when there is a current flowing through an infinitely long wire, this current creates a magnetic field, now I know that this magnetic field has energy that is capable of doing work!

So, I now came to the conclusion that this violates the principle of conservation of energy but I know it has to be true that energy is conserved, so what is wrong with my logic?

Answer (score 3):

> when there is a current flowing through an infinite long wire there, this current creates a magnetic field through it, now I know that this magnetic field is capable of doing work

There is no need for an infinitely long wire. A finite loop also stores energy in the magnetic field.

> what is wrong with my logic?

You are neglecting the energy required to run the current through the wire. The energy in the magnetic field comes from the energy supplied by the current. Even if the wire has no resistance energy will still be required to increase the current.